# issue renaming package in android studio

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to rename my app package name in android studio because when I try to upload to google play it says prefix "com.example" is reserved. So I've been to manifest file - double click in "example" and then refractor this, changed to "myapps" and changed it in the whole project. 
Now I try to upload it and I still get the same error message. Anybody knows how to fix this error ?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: package name is important and must be unique, "com.myapss" isn't unique enough! also take care of package names in java classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems simple. There are many ways from which one is this:

After you change the name manually in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, you click on the `R.java` class and then press F6.

`R.java` resides in the `app/build/generated/source/r/debug/(packagename)` directory. It contains resource IDs for the things you use in the android app. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698808/in-android-applications-what-is-the-role-of-r-java) question for more information.

Also, Amir is right, try to use a more unique package name. Example: com.(familyname) or your company domain.

For further information, you can visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600329/how-do-i-rename-the-android-package-name) question.

Comment: sorry for the newbie question but what file is r.java class ??

Comment: @user3033437 - No problem, starters have started the learning process so they take time to understand the things. You can check the edit I did to my answer to get the answer to your question.