# About R.java of Android development

Tags: android, android-resources, r.java-file

You see, I am beginning to working with Android development, and confused. For the sake of not making too much misspelling, I would like to just ask the questions:

1. There are many R.java in different packages as you can see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/classes.html#letter_R), so what is the differences between these R.java files? If they are the same, then what is the purpose of keeping these R.java files?
2. Does there exist an incredible relationship between these R.java files with that one in the project, which can be dynamically self-edited?
3. As I creating my "Hello" Activity which extends class AppCompatActivity in android.support.v7.app package, and beginning to say hello to the world, I came across my problem: does this mean from this very point on, my project has nothing to do with the package known as android.app?

Most important, any help and guide would be appreciated from the bottom of my heart, and please keep this in mind: I'm a clumsy beginner, but humble, and very hungry to learn.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. You should check: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: It associates your resources to unique ids.

Comment: Related reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004906/what-is-the-concept-behind-r-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698808/in-android-applications-what-is-the-role-of-r-java

Comment: Oh, and from official developer docs: [Accessing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html)

Answer (score 2):

There's two main uses of R.java

1) You reference **your own resources** such as layouts, strings, ids etc, all those resources, you yourself created using constants from  `yourpackage.R.java` file

That is, your string `String mystring = getString(R.string.mystr)`
will refer to `<string name="mystr>blalbabla</string>` in your `strings.xml` file

2) Exactly the same, you can refer **existing android resources** by means of android's R.java such as:

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
```

This `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`  is a layout android already has for you (which is a simple list item, with a text in it only)

Other libraries or submodules can have their own R.java, used the same way.

Comment: Thank you, problems almost solved. And why this snippet could cause my App crash?

Comment: Intent intent=getIntent();
        TextView textView=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.tvid);
        textView.setText(intent.getStringExtra("DATA").toString());

Comment: Probably intent.getStringExtra("DATA") is null. You should make sure it's not null before calling toString() on it

Comment: When I created View with code in run time instead of XML, it performed well, so in this case intent.getStringExtra("DATA") is not null. When Views are created with XML statically, does there exist some tricks to manage these Views in run time dynamically? Something like the static against the dynamic, only be one or another with no other choices....

Comment: getIntent().getStringExtra("DATA") just takes the intent with which you started your activity and returns a value for "DATA" you previously put in there by some putXXX(). Does not have to do with view inflation

Answer (score 0):

short answer :
R file is being build by your builder and you don't touch it ever
it maps your resources into integers which helps you to refer them easily

Comment: Thank you for answering, which means I do make sense. And how about a long answer for why the R file keep so many references to begin, even if I  didn't create an id, String or some else? Or R file built by the builder must be something to do with the R files in those different packages as mentioned above.

Comment: there are some resource by default in your application before you even start coding like some colors or layouts or ... ,which couse your application  to have some default refrences in R file

Comment: Why should the builder do that? I mean, if there are no objects to refer to, why the builder bather to create those references by default? And if they are necessary, how to take good use of those references?