# Jadx generated R.java does not contain resource id to map to a resource in strings.xml

Tags: android, decompiler

I am trying to decompile and deobfuscate my proguard obfuscated sample.apk.

Jadx is generating code like this for a line in my proguard obfuscated sample.apk:

```
ctx.getString(2131034163);
```

which usually maps to a resource in gen/R.java as:

```
public static final class string {
    public static final int save_exists=0x7f050033; 
}
```

However the R.java that is generated through Jadx looks like:

```
public final class R {
    public static final int ActionBarLayout_android_layout_gravity = 0;
    public static final int ActionBar_background = 10;

static {
        ActionBar = new int[]{p050c.p051a.p052a.p053a.R.height, p050c.p051a.p052a.p053a.R.title, p050c.p051a.p052a.p053a.R.navigationMode, p050c.p051a.p052a.p053a.R.displayOptions, p050c.p051a.p052a.p053a.R.homeAsUpIndicator};
    }
}
```

So, how can I map 2131034163 to a resource in strings.xml? Is it possible?

Comment: Hi friend,I think cannot. R.java is auto generated

Answer (score 1):

**`R.java`** is **`Auto-Generated`** file .

> Android R.java is an auto-generated file by aapt (Android Asset
>   Packaging Tool) that contains resource IDs for all the resources of
>   res/ directory . Don't try to Customize on it .

Read **[What is the concept behind R.java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004906/what-is-the-concept-behind-r-java)**

Answer (score 1):

If anyone might still search for the answer where to find Resource/Strings in decompiled jadx I would recommend looking at 'Resources/resources.ars/res/values' and there in strings.xml

At least in the one exercise I am solving right now they can be found there.