# what is the important of build.gradle and R.java file in Android Studio?

Tags: android, build, build.gradle, r.java-file

"Gradle: Execution failed for task ':Results:processDebugResources'

> Running /home/mydata/Desktop/android-studio/sdk/build-tools/android-4.2.2/aapt failed.

R.java file is empty, I don't know wheather the above error is the reason or not. My R.java is located in src/main/gen/com/example/results

Comment: R.java :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004906/what-is-the-concept-behind-r-java

Gradle : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16754643/what-is-gradle-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

-Migrate project to androidx

-Raise the minSDK and targetSDK

-update all dependencies to the newest version

This issue usually comes from an issue with a dependency in your build gradle. Either one is not compatible or up to date with the rest of the dependencies or the version you are using is bugged.